# Magento: Obtain Id for order, listening to the event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action

Tags: events, module, magento-1.4

When I look at the event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action` and works, but I can not get the Id of the newly created order.

Anyone have any idea??

Use magento-1.4.1.0

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The event is dispatched like this:

```
Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_onepage_controller_success_action', array('order_ids' => array($lastOrderId)));
```

So to get the last orderId, simply make your observer method like this:

```
public function orderSuccessEvent($observer)
{
    $observer->getData('order_ids'));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an answer provided by Branko Ajzele and I've just successfully tested:

```
        $order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
    $incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
    $order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
```

Thanks to him and hope it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

That event probably gets called before the action itself executes. Can you use `sales_order_save_after` instead?

---

EDIT: Here's your ID code. In your observer:

```
public function setLinkStatus($observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder(); 
    $id = $order->getId();

    // do something useful
}
```

Comment: If you also work, but as I get the id?

I am a little lost


Thanks

Comment: I've added the code you need to get the ID from that event. If you need more clarification on how to set up an observer, others have covered that in other questions in great detail.

Comment: I already tried that, and does not work,

thank you very much

continue to investigate ...

Comment: Okay, in what way did it not work? This code was pulled from app/code/core, so it works normally. Do you get an error? do you intercept the event at all? A little more detail, please.

Comment: $order->getId() doesn't get me the same order id that's on the backend.

Answer (score 0):

The Onepage Checkout controller in the Magento version 1.4.1 is not updated to have functions that can obtain the Order ID and thus you cant have the order object and data from the event observer. To have this working in Magento 1.4.1 simply update your OnepageController with the necessary functions.

The best approach would be to create your own module and override the core controller.

Add this in the config xml of your module so that your controller is called before the core OnepageController.

```
<frontend><routers><checkout><use>standard</use><args><modules><MyCompany_MyModule before="Mage_Checkout">MyCompany_MyModule</MyCompany_MyModule></modules></args></checkout></routers></frontend>
```

Hope this helps