# Magento - Hook into Admin login action

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I just finished reading

```
http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/how-hook-magento-event
```

but I am not sure how to find the different actions/events, for example, the above link refers to the action/event

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

How do I find those variables? A good example is, I would like to hook into the Admin login action, how would I find the correct _success_action for that event?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Jeff

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676941/magento-obtain-id-for-order-listening-to-the-event-checkout-onepage-controller

Comment: Is there a list of these events somewhere?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/events

Comment: thats awesome, thank you! Can you post that as the answer?

Comment: ahhh, actually, not the answer, the admin login success event isn't there, does this event even exist?

Comment: If you're just looking for the admin log in event it is `admin_session_user_login_success`. I haven't been able to find a complete list for core events yet.

Comment: i don't think it exists. or else it's deprecated. all my searches led me to echo Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('youradminurl/controller/action');

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events includes the admin session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/magento_events  lists all/most  the magento events

also look at

```
   Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->getUrl('youradminurl/controller/action');
```

Answer (score 2):

The best source is here: http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/

You can see `admin_session_user_login_success` there.

*Edit: Sorry - didn't see those last two comments...*

Comment: that's okay!! always try to help... :)