# Get custom attribute of products from observer order object Magento

Tags: magento

I am trying to get a custom attribute in from a product in an observer.
I have the following:

```
public function export_new_order($observer){
    $orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');
    foreach($orderIds as $_orderId){
        $order     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_orderId);
        Mage::log($order->debug());
    }
}
```

Which works fine, I get a nice print_r in my log.
However, when I try to get items it doesn't work.

I tried this:

```
public function export_new_order($observer){
    $orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');
    foreach($orderIds as $_orderId){
        $order     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_orderId);
        Mage::log($order->debug());
        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        Mage::log($items->debug());
    }
}
```

Also this:

```
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
Mage::log($items->debug());
```

But none of those work, i get a white screen whenever I click "Place order"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Feed_Sales>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Feed_Sales>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <feedsales>
            <class>Feed_Sales_Model_Order_Observer</class>
        </feedsales>
    </models>
    <events>
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
            <observers>
                <feed_sales_model_order_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Feed_Sales_Model_Order_Observer</class>
                    <method>export_new_order</method>
                </feed_sales_model_order_observer>
            </observers>
        </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
    </events>
</global>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe, you're getting the items just fine, the problem is somewhere else. Collections don't have **debug** method, so if you look into your server logs, most likely you will find an error about that.

So if you want to debug the items, you should do something like this:

```
public function export_new_order($observer){
    $orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');
    foreach($orderIds as $_orderId){
        $order     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_orderId);
        Mage::log($order->debug());
        $items = $order->getAllItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            Mage::log($item->debug());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. How would I go about retrieving a custom attribute from this product?

Comment: Well, Order Item is not the same as Product (it doesn't have all the data), so you need to get product with $item->getProduct() and then work with it as you would work with product - $item->getProduct()->getMyCustomAttribute() or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get order as follows and then get items for that order

```
$order = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order();
$incrementId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order->loadByIncrementId($incrementId);
```

This is shown in following link.

[Magento: Obtain Id for order, listening to the event checkout_onepage_controller_success_action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3676941/magento-obtain-id-for-order-listening-to-the-event-checkout-onepage-controller)

Answer (score 0):

There are issue with paramter fetch.

For getting order id try this

```
 $orderIds = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();
```

you need change model prefix class name:

**to:**

```
<class>Feed_Sales_Model</class>
```

**From:**

```
 <class>Feed_Sales_Model_Order_Observer</class>
```

And

From:

```
 <class>Feed_Sales_Model_Order_Observer</class>
```

to

```
 <class>feedsales/order_observer</class>
```

file location should be app/code/YOurMOduleCodePool/Feed/Sales/Model/Order/Observer.php